# Determine if the given date range has a pattern

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I'm dealing with an algorithm in a project where I need to traverse a range of date (sorted) and I need to check if the dates follow a specific pattern. Here is the list of all possible patterns to detect:

- *None* (No pattern detected. Just a random bunch of dates)
- 4 Mondays in a row
- 4 Tuesdays in a row
- 4 Wednesdays in a row
- 4 Thursdays or more in a row
- 4 Fridays or more in a row
- 4 Saturdays or more in a row
- 4 Sundays or more in a row
- Mon, Tue, Wed, and Thu together
- Tue, Wed, Thu, and Fri together
- Wed, Thu, Fri, and Sat together
- Thu, Fri, Sat, and Sun together
- Every other Monday
- Every other Tuesday
- Every other Wednesday
- Every other Thursday
- Every other Friday
- Every other Saturday
- Every other Sunday

All these patterns can be a represent through an Enum. I need to detect through a function, the pattern that the user given date range matches to.

Now, each pattern has a condition attached as well. For example:

**4 Mondays in a row** requires that the date collection must have at least 4 dates and if there are over four, the total number of dates must be a true as -> *number of dates* MOD 4 == 0

**Mon, Tue, Wed, and Thu together** requires date collection to have at least 4 dates without gaps and if there are over four, the total number of dates must be a true as -> *number of dates* MOD 4 == 0

Any help would be appreciated. Regards.

Comment: We wont write it for you, what have you come up with so far, this seems fairly simple.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class for each pattern that you want to match (all classes inherit from a base), have something like a "feed" method to pass a date to it, run the data through all those pattern classes, then have some kind of evaluate method on the pattern classes that will tell you if the criteria was met

Comment: That's what i originally did. Thing is, I'm trying get the smallest code to handle this. The class-way was adopted because the client didn't know if there was to be  another pattern(s) to detect. But now, the total number of patterns have been determined and really, its used only once.